# How to force a linebreak?

Tags: markdown, line-breaks

I've noticed that if I start a new paragraph right after an image, most renderers leave inadequate space between the image and the text below. The paragraph ends up looking like a legend. While this is useful when I do want to have a legend, sometimes I'd just like to insert an image in between two paragraphs, and have it adequately spaced below as above.

I correct this issue currently with:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit:

[IMAGE]

<br/><br/>

Pellentesque pharetra turpis vitae velit consequat placerat. Duis sed volutpat neque, et scelerisque orci.
```

But this strikes me as inelegant: I would like to avoid the HTML if possible.

Is there another way to force a linebreak?

I'm using Markdown Preview Plus for Atom to render.

Comment: maybe handle this with css? `.your-text-container img {margin:20px 0px;}`

Comment: @Sharky Wouldn't that make it even more complicated? Or can you inline CSS in Markdown?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

## tl;dr

In short, you can't with pure Markdown. You need to use raw HTML and/or CSS styles. The simplest is to insert `<br/><br/>` into your document.

## The long explanation

Browsers determine how to display the various HTML elements in a page by obtaining instructions from style sheets. Those style sheets can be obtained from multiple sources: (1) the browser's default style sheets, (2) local user-defined style sheets, (3) style sheets provided by the document author, and (4) inline styles embedded in the HTML ([this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Style_Computation) fascinating, albeit lengthy, article breaks down the entire process).

What we want to consider is the first; the browser's default style sheets. These tell the browser the default styles for the various elements, the padding of a paragraph, the size of the different level headers, the indentation and bullets of list items, etc. In fact, a quick [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=reset+css) turns up a whole slew of so-called "reset" style sheets which undo all these default styles.

This is what you are encountering, the default styles are not providing sufficient padding between the image and the paragraph following it. You have a few options to address this:

1. Define a user style sheet (stored on your local machine) which your browser would use to alter/override the default style sheet. Of course, this would only effect you on that machine. Any other machine would still use the default styles.
2. Define a style sheet for your page which gets attached to the page through a template or something. However, if you are posting your documents on a host which doesn't allow such control (like a wiki), then that won't help either.
3. Define some inline styles within the document. Of course, this means you would need to define raw HTML for your image. And on some services, the raw HTML and/or inline CSS might be stripped out.

In the end it all depends on how you intend to use your documents. But that don't really answer your question. How can you accomplish this in Markdown? In short, you can't.

As the author of Markdown [explains](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) (emphasis preserved):

> Markdown's syntax is intended for one purpose: to be used as a
>   format for *writing* for the web.
>
> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. Its
>   syntax is very small, corresponding only to a very small subset of
>   HTML tags. The idea is *not* to create a syntax that makes it easier
>   to insert HTML tags. In my opinion, HTML tags are already easy to
>   insert. The idea for Markdown is to make it easy to read, write, and
>   edit prose. HTML is a *publishing* format; Markdown is a *writing*
>   format. Thus, Markdown's formatting syntax only addresses issues that
>   can be conveyed in plain text.

If you are concerned about padding between elements, you are concerned with *formatting*, not *writing*, which is beyond the intended scope of Markdown. Yes, it is possible to revert to raw HTML (possibly with embedded inline CSS) to force your desired *formatting*, but that is exactly how it is supposed to work. In fact, the next paragraph in the above quoted document states:

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown's syntax, you simply
>   use HTML itself. There's no need to preface it or delimit it to
>   indicate that you're switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use
>   the tags.

So, the appropriate way to address your issue is with raw HTML and/or CSS, not with some special Markdown syntax.

Comment: For anyone trying to answer the same question as me, the short answer: `<br/><br/>` is your best bet.

Comment: It **is** possible in Markdown. You need to have two or more spaces at the end. However, with most editors and environments stripping trailing white spaces in all files, this could be problematic and easy to miss so I think the `<br/>` option is the way to go.

Comment: I am facing same issue, I replaced \n with <br/> tags and now it displays correct line breaks, but in case you are trying to draw a list with asterisks * it doesn't render list, instead it just breaks lines and some cases * is not visible as well. Did anyone face same issue?

Comment: Apparently, as said in several answers, adding two spaces at the end of the first line also works to force a single line break. Putting a \ also seems to work.

Comment: thank you! in my case (sharepoints markdown) adding a dot and 2 spaces at the end of the word fixes the problem

example:

**sample header**.<space><space>
sample description

Thanks!

Comment: After the other answers show that it *is* possible, this answer seems a bit off. Although the hint with the <br> might still be preferred by some, I would rephrase the claim "you can't"; also, @Superbest may want to accept one of the markdown-native answers since the question was how to do it in markdown.

Answer (score 166):

Line break in Markdown is "two or more spaces at the end of the line".

Comment: Please improve your answer by substantiating what you've stated (for example, a snippet from the documentation with a link would be perfect).

Comment: I have added another answer, based on this, since two space is considered correct.

Comment: I'm guessing that the author would like a way to do this in a single line, for something like prompting on the command line for a description.

Comment: Tnx, it was my question for a long time. a practical answer

Answer (score 77):

**Short answer**: two spaces at the end of the line

**Details**:

I am providing an updated answer, since @xof's answer, which while was incomplete was correct ([per the docs](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#block)):

> When you do want to insert a <br /> break tag using Markdown, you end a line with two or more spaces, then type return.
>
> Yes, this takes a tad more effort to create a <br />, but a simplistic “every line break is a <br />” rule wouldn’t work for Markdown. Markdown’s email-style blockquoting and multi-paragraph list items work best — and look better — when you format them with hard breaks.

Also, this has the extra benefit of avoiding the document unnecessarily becoming a mix of markdown and HTML. This retains readability, for when a Markdown viewer is not available, such as in a terminal window.

**Just one thing: don't do a global trim on trailing spaces, as is often habit for source code, otherwise you'll lose important formatting.**

Answer (score 55):

A Backslash `\` at the end of the line does also seem to work. And it is not removed by trailing space removal.

Comment: Even if it looks more like a comment than an answer, it works. And nobody else mentioned this solution, so thanks @tweber.

Comment: 100% this should be selected answer.

Comment: Great when your editor strips trailing spaces (you could configure your editor not to do it on md files, but there are no guarantees that all your colleagues will do it too!).

Comment: This is not supported by all markdown parsers though, which is why this solution is not recommended (at least not as the preferred solution): https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#line-break-best-practices

Comment: I mainly use markdown in the wiki feature of Azure DevOps and the backslash is a more flexible option than two spaces in that tool. It allows empty lines to be added while maintaining the indentation in a list, i.e.  
<some text>\ <type return>
\ <type return>  
Two spaces will not work on an empty line.

Answer (score 14):

According to the Markdown Guide, in order to force a new line, you need to add 2 spaces at the end of the line, followed by the return key.

See the guide here. https://markdown-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#line-return

I sometimes get a funky behaviour when simply entering a carriage return on my markdown documents. But following this guide, I was able to force a new line just by adding 2 spaces at the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred solution is add 2 spaces to the end of lines. I wrote a helper to do this where needed and it seems to work well for my needs:

```
  lines_with_spaces = text.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/).map do |line|
    (line.empty? || line[-2,2] == "  ") ? line : "#{line}  "
  end
  markdown_text_with_spaces = lines_with_spaces.join("\r")
```

Gets each line, adds 2 spaces to end of line if it doesn't already have them and the line isn't blank.

Comment: is this bash  code?

Comment: That's Ruby code